# Simplify $\frac{\sqrt{x^4 +3 x^2}}{x}$

Tags: calculus

The question states to simplify $$\frac{\sqrt{x^4 +3 x^2}}{x}$$where x is **negative**.

and part b is Let g(x) be the result from the simplification. Are f and g two equal functions? Y/N?

Much help is appreciated as i am struggling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{\sqrt{x^{4}+3x^{2}}}{x}=\frac{\sqrt{x^{2}(x^{2}+3)}}{x}=\frac{|x|}{x}\sqrt{x^{2}+3}=\frac{-x}{x}\sqrt{x^{2}+3}=-\sqrt{x^{2}+3}$

$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x^{4}+3x^{2}}}{x}$ and $g(x)=-\sqrt{x^{2}+3}$ will agree as functions for all $x<0$ but the formula for $f$ is not defined at $0$.

Comment: OH ok ok, thanks once again!

Comment: You're welcome once again!

Answer (score 0):

If $x<0$, then, $\sqrt{x^2} \, = \, \vert x \vert \,\equiv \,-x$.

Because this is the case,

$ f(x) \, := \, \frac{\sqrt{x^4+3x^2}}{x},$

$ \text{when $x<0$, } f(x) \, \equiv \, (-x) \frac{\sqrt{x^2+3}}{x} \, \equiv \, -\sqrt{x^2+3}.$

Now, from the simplification we see that this is only true when $x < 0$.

If we accept the typical idea that the domain of $f(x)$ is the largest subset of the real numbers $\{x \, \vert \, x \in \mathbf{R} \text{ such that } f(x) \in \mathbf{R} \}$, then $f : \mathbf{R} - \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$, but, we've restricted $g:\mathbf{R}_{<0} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$.  Thus $f$ and $g$ cannot be equivalent, because they do not share domains, i.e. $f(1) = 2$ and $g(1)$ Does.Not.Exist.

However, if we restrict the domain of $f$ to $\mathbf{R}_{<0}$ as well, there should be no points where $f$ and $g$ differ; they are equivalent.

I guess it all depends on whether x negative applies to the domain of $f$ as well.

Hopefully that answers your question.

Comment: haha, user71352 beat me :-D

Comment: Haha thanks man! lol yeah he beat you to it

Answer (score -1):

The answer is $\sqrt{x^2 + 3}$, and I don't know yet how to display so nicely...